# Problems with inheriting the correct property with the child class in python

Tags: python

I am needing to have the child class inherit from the parent class. I continue to either get "TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'species'" or the name is often getting assigned to the name and name continues to return back as none.

```
import unittest
import time

class Mammal:
   """ A Mammal class to further populate our animal kingdom """

   def __init__(self, species, name):
       """ mammal constructor can initialize class attributes """
       self.species = species
       self.name = None

   def eat(self, food):
       """ a method that will 'eat' in O(n) time """
       i = food
       print(self.name, "the", self.species, "is about to eat")
       while i >= 1:
           time.sleep(0.1)
           i = i // 2
       print("    ", self.name, "is done eating!")

   def makeNoise(self):
      """ a method that should be implemented by children classes """
      raise NotImplementedError("this method should be implemented by child class")
```

ADD ANY OTHER BASE CLASS METHODS YOU NEED/WANT TO HERE

```
def __eq__(self, object):
   return isinstance(object, Mammal) and object.species == self.species
```

THE FOLLOWING TWO CLASSES NEED TO BE COMPLETED, AND YOU
NEED TO REPLACE/DELETE ALL OF THE ELLIPSES SHOWN BELOW

```
class Hippo(Mammal):
   def __init__(self, name, species):
       self.name = name
       self.species = 'hippo'
   def getName(self):
       return self.name
   def setName(self, h):
       self.name = h
   def makeNoise(self):
       return 'grunting'

class Elephant(Mammal):
   def __init__(self, name, species):
       self.name = name
       self.species = 'elephant'
   def getName(self):
       return self.name
   def setName(self, e):
       self.name = e
   def makeNoise(self):
       return 'trumpeting'

class TestMammals(unittest.TestCase):
   """ a class that is derived from TestCase to allow for unit tests to run """

   def testInheritance(self):
       """ confirm that Elephant and Hippo are children classes of Mammal """
       self.assertTrue(issubclass(Elephant, Mammal) and issubclass(Hippo, Mammal))

def testEqOperator(self):
       hip1 = Hippo('John')
       hip2 = Hippo('Arnold')
       self.assertEqual(hip1, hip2)
def main():
   """ a 'main' function to keep program clean and organized """
   print("-------------------- start main --------------------")
   e = Elephant("Ellie")
   h = Hippo("Henry")
   if(e == h):
      print(e.getName(), "and", h.getName(), "are of the same species")
   else:
      print(e.getName(), "and", h.getName(), "are *not* of the same species")

   def listenToMammal(Mammal):
      print(Mammal.makeNoise())

   listenToMammal(e)
   listenToMammal(h)

   e.eat(100)
   print("--------------------- end main ---------------------")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    unittest.main()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6kfi.png)
this is what the output should look like but im confused

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Your code is not minimal, and you have not clearly shown the problem with your output.

Comment: We expect you to perform basic diagnosis to include with your post.  At the very least, print the offending values at the point of error and trace them back to their sources.

Comment: `Hippo.__init__()` is defined to require two arguments, but you're only passing one here `hip1 = Hippo('John')`.

Answer (score 0):

You are still defining `Hippo.__init__` to take 2 arguments, even though you ignore the species argument. You can drop that one. You should also use `Mammal.__init__` rather than setting the attributes yourself.

```
class Hippo(Mammal):
   def __init__(self, name):
       super().__init__(self, name, species='hippo')
   def getName(self):
       return self.name
   def setName(self, h):
       self.name = h
   def makeNoise(self):
       return 'grunting'
```

`getName` and `setName` aren't necessary; you can access the `name` attribute directly

Comment: I am still getting that species is getting multiple values